# App Not Grabbing HTML

Tags: android, html, android-emulator, web-scraping

Edit:

Error:

```
06-12 19:25:55.880: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
06-12 19:25:55.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-12 19:25:55.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):     at com.laytproducts.songmaster.mainAct$1.onClick(mainAct.java:124)
06-12 19:25:55.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
06-12 19:25:55.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
06-12 19:25:55.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
06-12 19:25:55.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
06-12 19:25:55.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-12 19:25:55.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-12 19:25:55.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-12 19:25:55.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
....
```

code:

```
rawHtml = getHtml(baseSite + rSearched); //get the raw html of page
if(rawHtml == null || rawHtml.length() < 1){//checks if it really contains anything
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: Got No Result", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.e("RawHtml Error:1", "Nothing In rawHtml String");
} else {
    for(int i = 1; i < 7; i++){
        String html = parseHtml(rawHtml,i);
        if(html == null || html.length() < 1){
            results[i-1] = "Result not found:Please try different lyrics";
        } else {
            results[i-1] = parseHtml(rawHtml,i); //error here
        }
    }
}
```

parseHtml:

```
public String parseHtml(String html,int num){
    String parsed = "";
    String artistParse = "";
    String songParse = "";
    //String fullHtmlParse = "#NUMBER#. &nbsp;<span>This Charming Man</span> &nbsp; by Smiths</a>";//Reference
    if(num != 0 && num <= 6){
        songParse = StringUtils.substringBetween(html,num+". &nbsp;<span>","</span>");
        artistParse = StringUtils.substringBetween(html,num+". &nbsp;<span>"+songParse+"</span> &nbsp; by ","</a>");
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Error: Number is wrong in parseHtml, Please Try Again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("ParsedHtml Error:1","Error: Number in parseHtml is invalid: " + num);
        return "";
    }
    parsed = songParse + ":" + artistParse;
    return parsed;
}
```

getHtml:

```
public String getHtml(String url){
    String html = "";
    String baseHtml = "";
    String table = "";
    try {
        baseHtml = new StringReader(url).toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error getting HtmlDoc, Please Try Again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
    if(baseHtml == null || baseHtml.length() < 1){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error getting HtmlDoc, Please Try Again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("BaseHtml Error:1","Error: Nothing in baseHtml[method getHtml(String url)]");
        return "";
    } else {
        //table = StringUtils.substringBetween(baseHtml,"<!-- EyesLyrics.com search results -->","</table>");
    }
    html = baseHtml;
    return html;
}
```

Hope that is what you need.

Comment: Just realized... Since none of the other checks go off it must be an issue with the "table" portion of the code...

Comment: This won't resolve your problem, but it's good practice to put the null check before any other checks.  So instead of if(x == "" || x == null), do if(x == null || x == "").  even though in this case it doesn't really matter.

Comment: So I should check for null first?

Comment: So I have a feeling it has to do with my parsing rather than my html.

Because I removed the part that parses into the table, now I am getting an error when trying to parse out the information (NullPointerException)

So I think I am doing that wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the Toast appear, you'll need to call the `show()`-method. Like this:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error getting HtmlDoc, Please Try Again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) for more details.

---

```
if(rawHtml == "" || rawHtml == null){[...]}
```

I guess the `rawHtml`-object is a String? In that case, if you want to check if this String is empty, you would neither use the `equals("")`-method or check for the String's length:

```
if (rawHtml.length < 1)
```

Also, if you need to check if the String is `null`, you should do that first, because the check for the length (for example) would cause a `NullPointerException`.

---

### About your code

```
if(rawHtml == null ...
```

Testing if `rawHtml` is null is unnecessary, because in the `getHtml`-method, you crate it as an empty String. It will never be `null`.

```
return "";
```

You return an empty String in your `parseHtml` and `getHtml`-methods. I would rather return `null` and then check if the returned value is `null`. You can spare one condition with the same effect.

```
results[i-1] = "...";
```

The calculation should be done in brackets, like this:

```
results[(i-1)] = "...";
```

Your error aperas to be on this line:

```
results[i-1] = parseHtml(rawHtml,i);
```

As I can't see if you initialize the `results`-object, I guess this is your problem. Before you can access (write or read) an element in this array, the array needs to be initialized.

This is how you would do this, guessing your array is a String-array:

```
String[] results = new String[NumberOfElements];
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Actually didn't realize I didn't put that. Thanks,
but that still doesn't fix my other issues xD

Comment: I updated my post. Please be more specific what your actual error is. Also, if you can control what the output format is, i would rather use XML and a XML-Parser to do that.

Comment: I have heard of such method. But I am not exactly sure about the pages XML. That is why I was trying to just use HTML

Comment: So you control weather the returned content is XML or HTML? In that case, you would use XML or even JSON. Just Google for it, it's not that hard.

Comment: I do not think the web page I am trying to grab has XML. But I do not know how to tell if it does. I "Inspect Element" (google chrome) and only thing that shows up is JavaScript and HTML

Comment: Wow... Missed something huge.

`### WARNING: could not add DNS server '192.168.1.1' to the network stack`

Found that in console, not DDMS

edit:

only appears when closing emulator. Nvm might not be that important then

Comment: So you're not responsible for the returned content. And place specify the problem you're having (because i can't tell from what you wrote).

Comment: No I am not. Well I am 100% sure what the problem is. I am getting a null exception error when trying to parse the html data I got (although it might be that I didnt get any data at all).

Comment: Well, post the LogCat output and we'll have a look at it.

Comment: `06-12 19:25:55.880: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
06-12 19:25:55.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-12 19:25:55.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(226):     at com.laytproducts.songmaster.mainAct$1.onClick(mainAct.java:124)`  the line is this: `results[i-1] = parseHtml(rawHtml,i);`  thats the html parsed. (trying to get the html i need into an array)

Comment: Okay, you should edit your post and show all code-parts which are necessary to understand your problem. The line alone doesn't help, we need some context.

Comment: thanks man. I understand a lot more now. Hopefully I can fix the error now :) *Best Answer*